# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]: Variable Filenames with open()

Tags: xml, python-3.x, web-scraping, io

I am working on a **webscraper in Python** that gets name and downloadlink from an xml file. First, it concatenates a name from date, hof and az. Then it is supposed to download the file behind the ziplink (www.file.io/xyzfile.zip) and safe it under the concatenated name in the same directory.

Except it won't take my concatenated name. Hence the general question: What exact information do I need to supply as argument to the function? With type() I made sure I'd supply a string but it won't take it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = requests.get('https://www.rechtsprechung-im-internet.de/rii-toc.xml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml.text, 'xml')

for item in soup.find_all('item'):
    ziplink=str(item.link.text) 
    datum=str(item.find('entsch-datum').text)
    az=str(item.aktenzeichen.text)
    hof=str(item.gericht.text)
    name=datum+'-'+hof+'-'+az
    print(type(name))
    r=requests.get(ziplink, allow_redirects=True)
    with open('%s.zip' % name,'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
    print(name)
```

However unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple_script.py", line 26, in <module>
    with open('%s.zip' % name,'wb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20100114-BGH 9. Zivilsenat-IX ZB 72/08.zip'
```

With print(type()) I made sure that I supply a string as name parameter. Because when I tested the code with `name = 'test.zip'` it worked fine. However ideally  I would like to name the files dynamically.

This is my first Post on Stackoverflow and I would love to get some feedback. Thank you so much!

Cheers, Jasper

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "wb+" permission in the open function?

```
with open('%s.zip' % name,'wb+') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

The + means it should create the file if it isn't found.